# How to chain redux actions using returned result of the previous action?

Tags: reactjs, redux, redux-saga, redux-thunk, redux-persist

I'm building an app in React Native, and using Redux with [redux-persist](https://github.com/rt2zz/redux-persist) to act as on device database.

**The crux of the issue is, how do I return the result of a redux action, to then dispatch another action with this data?** Read on for more specifics.

The user can create custom habit types. When doing so, I dispatch an action to create a habit type in the store (e.g. "running"). This action generates a new unique `UUID` for the habit type. I then want to add this newly created habit type to a routine (e.g. "morning routine"), and so I need to receive back the `UUID` of the habit type and call another dispatch to add it to the routine.

I'm using [immer](https://github.com/immerjs/immer) to make manipulating the state in my reducers simpler, and have this code (simplified example):

```
import produce from "immer";

const userReducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case ADD_CUSTOM_HABIT_TYPE: {
      return produce(state, draftState => {
        const newHabitType = {
          id: generateUuid(),
          name,
        };

        draftState.customHabitTypes.push(newHabitType);

        return draftState;
      });
    }
  }
};
```

I'm then dispatching it in my component, like so (simplified):

```
dispatch({
  type: ADD_CUSTOM_HABIT_TYPE,
  name: "running",
});
```

How can I then say, after creating this new habit type, to dispatch another action and add it to my routine?

I've looked at [redux-thunk](https://github.com/reduxjs/redux-thunk) and [redux-saga](https://github.com/redux-saga/redux-saga/), and spent hours reading about these and trying to get redux-thunk to work, but to no avail. I'm sure this must be simple, but I'm coming up blank, and so maybe others are too, hence this post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A very simple solution would be to generate the unique id before dispatching the action.

**Example**

```
const newHabitType = {
  id: generateUuid(),
  name,
};

dispatch({
  type: ADD_CUSTOM_HABIT_TYPE,
  habit: newHabitType,
});

dispatch({
  type: ADD_CUSTOM_HABIT_TO_ROUTINE,
  habit: newHabitType.id,
});
```

**Pros**

1. You no longer need to chain actions per se, you just need to dispatch them in order.
2. This preserves one of the most important Redux guidelines: your reducer should not have any side effects (in your case, generating a random id). [reference](https://redux.js.org/style-guide/style-guide#reducers-must-not-have-side-effects)

**Cons**

1. If you create the new habits in multiple places, you will have to generate the unique ids in every place where you dispatch the action. This might lead to repeated code. The solution to this would be to encapsulate the whole logic for creating the habits to a single component and then reuse this component everywhere.

Comment: Hey Khaled, thanks for the reply here! I think you're right, I was pondering this myself but then the Con you mention came up, so I felt that there must be a redux way of doing things to enabled the `ADD_CUSTOM_HABIT_TYPE` action to fully encapsulate creating this new habit type (including the `UUID` generation). It seems from the docs you reference that this isn't the redux way. I'll see how I can encapsulate the logic in either a function, or a component depending on what fits best. Thanks for providing the clarification here.

Comment: Just an update here, using `redux-thunk` to create a function that generates the `UUID` and passes it to both dispatches (basically the exact code Khaled has above, just wrapped in a thunk) does the job nicely, and allows me to call `dispatch(ADD_CUSTOM_HABIT_TYPE_THUNK({ habit })`, with the thunk handling the UUID generation and both redux action calls.

Answer (score 0):

Actions do not return data per se, the are simply objects which mutate the store based on the rules defined in the reducer. Two possible solutions:

**Option A**, create a composite action.

```
const compositeAction = args => {
    return dispatch => {
        return someAsyncCall(args).then(response => {
           dispatch(addCustomHabitat(response))
           dispatch(followUpAction())
        }
    }
}

const addCustomHabitat = response => {
    return {
        type: "ADD_CUSTOM_HABIT_TYPE",
        data: response
    }
}

const followUpAction = () => {
    ...another action...
}
```

**Option B**, connect the results of the first action to the dispatching component through `react-redux` and pass them to the second action.

```
import {connect} from 'react-redux';

const MyReactComponent = props => {
    dispatch(addCustomHabitatTypeAction());

    if(props.customHabitatType !== undefined)
        dispatch(followUpAction(props.customHabitatType());

    return (
       ...JSX here...
    );
}

const mapStateToProps = state => {
    return {
        customHabitatType: state.userReducer.customHabitatType
    }
}

connect(mapStateToProps)(MyReactComponent);
```

I hope this helps! Please excuse my abbreviated code and let me know if you have any questions.

Comment: Thanks for the response here Daly! Let me try to understand things. In `Option A`, I think you're suggesting I move out the `UUID` creation from the action, put this into a new function `someAsyncCall` and then pass this new UUID to both the `ADD_CUSTOM_HABIT_TYPE` and `ADD_HABIT_TYPE_TO_ROUTINE` actions?

In `Option B`, I'm less clear. How does this component know what has changed? As there could be 5 existing custom habit types, after the change there will be 6, do I need to manually diff to get the new one? Not sure how this is supposed to work. Thanks!

Comment: For option A, if the `UUID` generation had to be performed asynchronously then yes you could use that approach. For option B, the component is re-rendered each time an action changes the value of `cusomHabitatType`. You could then use conditionals inside the component to make further decisions based on the value of that prop. In all honestly though I think Khaled's solution will better serve you by keeping the logic simple. : ) These are a bit more heavyweight options.

Comment: Thanks Daly, appreciate the thoughts and suggestions here! Having realised the "redux way" is to have no side effects, I think I'll look to refactor the UUID creation out similar to Khaled's solution.